# Get url from window.location with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Does anybody know how can i get a url between a javascript **window.location.href="url";**
using seleniumhq web-driver in java.

Imagine a flow like this.

Link Page > Page 2 > Page 3 > Final Page

`"Link Page"` has the link:

<a href="linkToPage2"> Link </a> and then Selenium clicks the link element with something like this:

> webElement.click();

`Page 2` executes the window.location.href="Page 3" and then `Page 3`
send the redirect to the `Final Page`.

is it possible to get the `url` from `Page 3` or even the history navigation?

Comment: I highly doubt it since JavaScript can not even tell you the pages in the history, just the length.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why dont u just store the URL when on the Link Page, and use it to navigate to directly when on step 3. (I am pretty sure i have got your question wrong.)

Comment: perlnewbie the url from Page 3 changes dynamically, and only Page 2 knows the link

Comment: i am not able to understand how would this relate to a real user flow? Will a user on ur site go back and then obtain the link and then navigate to that link, using the address bar? Could you please explain why you trying to do this? probably there is a better solution :)

Comment: I agree with @perlnewbie ... users don't care about redirects.  They care about where they were, and where they're going to.  The only reason I could think of is if the web site/web application is getting session information from a middle page.. or setting a hidden field.  And you need that value for some reason.

Comment: its exactly that.

"The only reason I could think of is if the web site/web application is getting session information from a middle page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in selenium webdriver (in Java):

```
String browserUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

You can also make javascript calls in selenium:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String browserUrl = (String) js.executeScript("return window.top.location.href.toString()");
System.out.println("Your browser URL is " + browserUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

> String url = selenium.getLocation();
>
> System.out.println(url);

Answer (score -1):

So far I cannot think of any other way than using a proxy that would record all requests made by browser. It is possible to set up such a proxy and control it from your code. You didn't specify the language you use for writing your tests. If it's Java then [Browsermob](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy) may be helpful. If it's C# take a look at [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/).